# ARToolKit: Sample app not showing animation

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

it may be a quite dumb question. Please bear me, being novice to AR and touching android after an era.

I downloaded and did setup ARToolKit. I am followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAWyUQ1xaNs) video for the setup.
Then, tried one of the examples, ARSimpleNativeCarsProj, in it.
But, not getting any cars animation on the screen. I tried with different flat surfaces on 2 devices.

Am I missing something any basic thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit strange, when tried on flat surface the animation of the car was not shown... but, when tried on the keyboard of my macbook, it is showing the car. So basically, there was nothing wrong in my setup.

To find out why it is not showing animation on flat surface, will do some investigation, and will update the post.